# extendible hashing - destructor C++

Tags: c++, hash

So... I have implemented a version of exendible hashing...my question now is for the destructor.

I used in the Hash class an array of pointers that point on buckets from class Bucket. The problem is there can be multiple pointers on the same bucket.

In the destructor of the Hash class I have to delete every bucket and then the array, but I have to be careful not to delete the same bucket twice (I think that'll result in an error). In order to do that I used a bool vector to memorize whether or not the bucket has already been deleted.

My question is now: is there a way to know if a bucket has already been deleted without using more memory (the bool vector) ?

LE: I solved the destructor problem using nullptr (seems to be working now), but...another question: how can I go through every bucket exactly 1 time (for finding the min and max elements, for example). I can't use nullptr this time (the pointers need to stay where they are - on the buckets)

Comment: Maybe consider using `std::shared_ptr`? It use 2-3 words of memory per objet plus the shared state, but it's often a good tradeoff for simplicity and safety.

Comment: You meet the same problem during normal operation. So, just `shared_ptr` and be done with it.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply...well, this is a project for the uni and I'm not really allowed to use std::shared_ptr...

Answer (score 0):

Just iteratively use your erase function

```
while (size ())
{
    erase(begin());
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by that? I have delete pointers[i];   ... where pointers[i] is one of the pointers. But if I delete it and then later (let's say pointers[j] where j > i) I have to delete it again I can't (because I already deleted it and pointers[j] points on something that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: I just thought I should delete the bucket and then set all the pointers that show on that bucket to point on NULL. Is that a good idea?
And another question... How can I browse (translated it with google translate..sorry if it's the wrong verb :D) every bucket exactly 1 time (for finding the min and max elements, for example)

Comment: Before you write yhe destuctor, that deletes evetything, figure out an erase function to remove just one

Answer (score 0):

> I used in the Hash class an array of pointers that point on buckets
>   from class Bucket. The problem is there can be multiple pointers on
>   the same bucket.
>
> My question is now: is there a way to know if a bucket has already
>   been deleted without using more memory (the bool vector) ?

Sure -- use reference counting.  Put an integer member variable in the Bucket class, initialized to zero.  Whenever you create a pointer to that Bucket object, increment the integer.  Whenever you invalidate a pointer to the Bucket (i.e. whenever you would have called delete on that pointer), decrement the integer member variable.  If that decrement causes the integer to become zero, you know the Bucket has no more pointers pointing to it, so delete the Bucket.

Comment: good idea...but using nullptr seemed easier :D...and apparently it's working